# Javascript: How to precent pics in sequence?

Tags: javascript

There are 3 pictures. I wanted to have them presented in sequence which will be: pic A(click)-pic B(click pic C). But now the situation is when I click on pic A, it jumps to pic C, skips pic B. Can anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

Thank you very much.

```
var pic_one = "./img/oneblur.png";//pic B
var pic_two = "./img/twoblur.png";//pic C
var pic = [pic_one, pic_two]
var change = document.getElementById("zero");//pic A
function changePic() {
  for (var k = 0; k < pic.length; k++) {
  change.setAttribute("src", pic[k]);
  console.log(k);
 }
}
change.addEventListener("click", changePic, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code you immediately change image to B and then to C with one click. Try this code:

```
var pic_one = "./img/oneblur.png";//pic B
var pic_two = "./img/twoblur.png";//pic C
var pic = [pic_one, pic_two]
var change = document.getElementById("zero");//pic A
function changePic() {
    k = change.getAttribute("src") == pic[0] ? 1 : 0;
  change.setAttribute("src", pic[k]);
  console.log(k);
}
change.addEventListener("click", changePic, false);
```

It checks what image is now displayed and sets variable k properly.

Comment: @Sylvia You welcome, however on StackOverflow it is better to select the provided answer as a solution than thanking in a comment. It will in turn convey your gratitude to the answer provider and what is most important it will help future users with similar problem. Happy coding!

Comment: got it!! (ง •̀ᴗ•́)ง